# how can my password contain special characters using jasypt and encrypt.sh?

Tags: jasypt

Trying to use the encrypt.sh utility and my password has special characters:

./encrypt.sh input="$%#!" password="your_jasypt_password" algorithm="PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC" keyObtentionIterations=1000 providerName="BC"

-bash: !": event not found

Answer (score 17):

Ok easy-- need to use single quotes instead of double quotes.