# Using jasypt to encrypt and decrypt an already encrypted password

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am using jasypt to encrypt and decrypt passwords. Jasypt provides excellent libraries to do this. However, the issue that I am facing revolves around encrypting/decrypting an already encrypted password. The encrypted password that I am speaking is not encrypted by jasypt. However, it contains characters that are not contained in normal passwords. As a result, the decrypted password (first encrypted by jasypt and then decrypted by jasypt) contains an extra character. Are there alternative classes that take into account already encrypted or hashed passwords with abnormal characters? I am utilizing the BasicTextEncryptor.

Comment: Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted, so there is something fundamentally wrong with the entire system in which this question is embedded. See [tag:password-encryption] for why.

Comment: @EJP there is no mention of user password. what about the password used for connecting to a system (DB), maintained in a property file.

Comment: @Albert could you share a simple void main type of sample snippet to let us understand the issue.

Comment: I fixed the issue by not using quotations when encrypting the value. Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388928/how-can-my-password-contain-special-characters-using-jasypt-and-encrypt-sh